Hacker rank Lena sort challenge: why the number of comparisons equals the sum of node depths?
I am looking at HackerRank challenge Lena Sort:

Lena developed a sorting algorithm described by the following pseudocode:
lena_sort(array nums) {
    if (nums.size <= 1) {
        return nums;
    }
    pivot = nums[0];
    array less;
    array more;
    for (i = 1; i < nums.size; ++i) {
      // Comparison
        if (nums[i] < pivot) {
            less.append(nums[i]);
        }
        else {
            more.append(nums[i]);
        }
    }
    sorted_less = lena_sort(less);
    sorted_more = lena_sort(more);
    ans = sorted_less + pivot + sorted_more;
    
    return ans;
}

We consider a comparison to be any time some nums[i] is compared with pivot.

My question concerns what is written in the editorial:

Notice that when we perform Lena Sort, at every stage one number becomes the pivot, all the others are compared to it and accordingly sent to one of the two arrays on which Lena Sort is applied again.
We can visualise this in the form of a binary tree:
Each node is labeled by the pivot at that step and the number of
comparisons is nothing but the sum of depths of each node

Why is number nothing but the sum of depths of each node?
What is the depth of node?

Unfortunately your question does not make sufficient sense without the content behind the remote link and the remote link is inaccessible without signing up/performing some other rituals. Please [edit] your question to be self-contained. An external link may be provided for extra context, but following it should not be required to understand your question.


What is the depth of node?

The depth of a node is the length of the path from the root to that node. The length of a path is given by the number of edges on that path. So the root has depth 0, its direct children have depth 1, ...etc.

Why is number nothing but the sum of depths of each node?

It may help to analyse an example. Let the input be [5, 2, 6, 1, 3, 4]
The first pivot is 5, and we get this tree after we place the other values in two sublists:
            5
         /     \
     [2,1,3,4]  [6]

Then we repeat the process for the subarray [2,1,3,4] where 2 becomes the pivot. And so we get:
           5
         /   \
        2    [6]
      /  \
    [1]  [3,4]  

The only subarray that has more than one element is [3,4]. The pivot is 3, and so we get:
Then we repeat the process for the subarray [2,1,3,4] where 2 becomes the pivot. And so we get:
           5
         /   \
        2    [6]
      /  \
    [1]   3
           \
           [4]  

The subarrays with just one element are the leaves of the tree, and represent base cases in the recursion.
With this example in mind, let's count how many times the value 1 was compared with a pivot.
In the first phase (when 5 was the pivot) it was compared once.
In the second phase (when 2 was the pivot) it was compared again, and that's it.
The general pattern here is that a value is compared with all its ancestors in the tree. If we look at 4: it was first compared with pivot 5, then with pivot 2, and finally with pivot 3, so it took part in three comparisons.
The number of ancestors a node has in a tree is exactly what the depth is of that node. And to count all comparisons we count all the times that any value (any node) was compared with any of its ancestors (in their role of pivots), i.e. we can sum up all the depths of all nodes.
